# Java remote MySQL vs HTTPRequest

Tags: java, mysql, json, httpwebrequest

I have a program that I recently wrote in Java that does a few things.  It mainly relies on getting data from a mysql database using connector/j.  The database is on a remote server (hosted in the netherlands).  This causes some issues with latency.  I recently became aware of the ability to use JSON in conjunction with Java.

So, my question:  If I have some kind of front-end script that I make http requests to in order to return json, an API of sorts, is this faster than using direct requests to mysql on the remote server? are they downsides to this?

Answer (score 1):

Technically the answer is 'it depends' :)

A couple of my thoughts here ...

I can say that from my experience its very rare case that your DB is opened to remote connections mainly because of security reasons.

On the other hand
When taking 'head-to-head' comparison, I would expect that JSON would be slower because you have http overhead here + JSON is by nature a text protocol of data representation (read not efficiently encoded when compared to serialized binary data).

Moreover this solution will require some sort of HTTP server between the database and your java client code. 
You should concert also question of data transport (inter process communication is in general slow), so if you place the http server far from the db server, the chances are that it will take a lot of time to bring your data.

Having said that there are yet a lot of things to mention:
 - When you're using json/xml/serialized objects (RMI)/ whatsoever you can '''preprocess''' your data - its a big deal really, because sometimes in general its more flexible than SQL.

- Data Caching. Sometimes you can pre-cache the data and even not to turn to the database.
- Figure out how the traffic to the db actually looks like. For example when you're using plain JDBC in Oracle, sometimes it can issue additional request to the db (you can use sniffer to see it) and bring additional chunk of data. It happens right in the famous loop:

  while( resultSet.next() ) {
    ///.... do your stuff
  }

It happens for big results usually.

- Maybe you can improve a lot the total processing time by optimizing the query itself but its a different story.

For me its usually worth to maintain something between the db and remote client, it just sounds right.

Hope this helps